# How to rewrite the routing url about two layer nest type with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I have a url like this:

```
http://example.com/bigcategory/1
http://example.com/bigcategory/1/smallcategory/1
http://example.com/bigcategory/1/smallcategory/2
```

The tables are:

### big_categories

### | id | name        |

### | 1  | color       |

### small_categories

### | id | name        | big_category_id   |

### | 1  | yellow      |1                  |

### | 1  | red         |2                  |

So I want to make the url like this:

```
http://example.com/color
http://example.com/color/yellow
http://example.com/color/red
```

Then how to make the routing file?

I know `to_param`:

```
def to_param
  name
end
```

Then `find_by(name: params[:name])`:

```
@big_category = BigCategory.find_by(name: params[:name])
@small_category = SmallCategory.find_by(name: params[:name])
```

But in this case, there are tow layer nest situation. I don't know how to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `friendly_id` gem, which uses a unique, human-readable slug for resources.
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id